# Using static method in Factory: Pros and Cons?

Tags: c++, factory

In C++, when you have a Factory class for an object, the method that creates the object may be used as one of the following:

**non-static method**:

Declaration:

```
class FooFactory{
    public:
        Foo* Create() {
            return new Foo(); 
        }
};
```

Usage

```
FooFactory fooFactory;
Foo* foo = fooFactory.Create();
```

**static method**:

Declaration:

```
class FooFactory{
    public:
        static Foo* Create() {
            return new Foo(); 
        }
};
```

Usage

```
Foo* foo = FooFactory::Create();
```

Using the static method avoids instantiating the factory, for instance.

Is this a good practice or are there any other good arguments in favor or against both solutions?

I'd appreciate a list of pros and cons that could help me and the community to choose which to use.

People should refrain from using opinions as I'm looking for feedback based on expert experience.

Comment: It depends. My opinion: if you care about performance, you should minimize the use of member functions. There was a CppCon talk called "free your functions", you might want to watch that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to choose one over the other is whether there is additional information that will change the instantiation. If the factory class has such information (and that information can vary rather than simply being set) then it makes sense for the factory method to be non-static. If the factory will simply create the object (or return the address of a function local static instance) there is no reason to require ath factory type be instantiated.

An example of when it would make sense for the factory method to be non-static would be a factory for database connection objects, you instantiate the factory, set whatever properties for the database connection you want then invoke CreateConnection() to get a connection object with the specified properties. This can be Superior to overloading the CreateConnection method with different parameter options because the properties can vary so much from one databse connection to another.

An example where it would make sense for the method to be static would be a method that returns an instance of the actual factory just described. That factory type is simply created, there is no tuning involved.

Comment: But in the case that the factory simply creates the object, you say that there is no reason to instantiate the factory but if we did, the result would be the same so, why should'nt we?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer. Couple more things.

`std::unique_ptr` is usually better than raw pointers.

Another one, if the only thing your class factory does is that call to `new Foo();` you don’t need a class factory at all. `FooFactory::Create();` is not longer than `std::make_unique<Foo>()`. Class factories are only useful when you’re de-serializing stuff, or when you’re constructing different classes based on arguments or some configs.

Comment: You're right about that this example is not valid for a factory as it is not needed at all. I did this intentionally to focus the problem with the static or not, and not the content which lead to many more examples.

Comment: A factory (along with release method_ can protect you from cross-library allocation issues. There are times that you really don't want to 'new' something where the code

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Good point, but IMO C++ ABI is way too fragile to be used across dynamic libraries. Besides malloc there’re issues with exceptions, CRT versions, conditional symbols… People usually use more reliable ABIs anyway, such as C API, or COM on Windows.